# Как получить данные из камеры?

Tags: c++, linux, c

Вообще хотел бы получить данные из камеры, преобразовать это в flv формат, и вывести по rtmp, но наверное это только мечта. Пробывал ffmpeg программу прочитать, я почему то уверен что там всё грамотно написано, но я ничего не понел. Вот хотел бы узнать как в линуксе можно открыть устройство камеру и получить видео поток, чтобы вывести его на экран.

Comment: пробывал fopen ( "/dev/video0", "r" ) но ничего не вышло.

Comment: Если это единственная ваша задача, то всё делается через консольную команду ffmpeg вообще без единой строчки кода на c++

Comment: Мне это для умения нужно. Хочу научиться делать и понимать как это делается. Я знаю что ffmpeg это умеет.

Comment: Здесь слишком много всякого - video4linux2 rgb/yuv, кодек h264, контейнер flv, протокол rtmp, который на базе tcp и udp. Изучение всего этого займёт много времени

Comment: Но если просто "открыть устройство камеру", то читайте что-нибудь про video4linux2

Comment: Вот например хочу я игру сделать. В игре будут разные ситуации, при которых камера будет записывать лицо игрока. Потом после прохождения уровня можно будет посмотреть на лицо, которое может быть менялось в зависимости от ситуации. Записать ffmpeg уже не получиться, потому как нужен код именно в игре, а может кому нибудь для игры и хватит ffmpeg.

Comment: Во-первых, ничто не мешает запустить программу ffmpeg из кода игры. Во-вторых, с vlc из принятого вами ответа абсолютно та же ситуация, так что мне непонятно, почему вы приняли этот ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Вот хотел бы узнать как в линуксе можно открыть устройство камеру и
>   получить видео поток, чтобы вывести его на экран.

```
vlc /dev/video0
```

> получить видео поток

[Документация по v4l2](https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/uapi/v4l/v4l2.html)

По замечанию @andreymal - краткий мануал

## Открытие устройства

```
int fd;

fd = open("/dev/video0", O_RDWR);
if (fd == -1) {
    // ...
}
```

## Подготовка к захвату кадров

```
struct v4l2_capability caps = {0};
if (-1 == ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QUERYCAP, &caps)) {
    // ...
}
```

## Формат кадра

```
struct v4l2_format fmt = {0};
fmt.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
fmt.fmt.pix.width = 320;
fmt.fmt.pix.height = 240;
fmt.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_MJPEG;
fmt.fmt.pix.field = V4L2_FIELD_NONE;

if (-1 == ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_S_FMT, &fmt)) {
    // ...
}
```

## Подготовка буфферов

```
struct v4l2_requestbuffers req = {0};
req.count = 1;
req.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
req.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;

if (-1 == ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_REQBUFS, &req)) {
    // ...
}

struct v4l2_buffer buf = {0};
buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
buf.index = bufferindex;
if(-1 == ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QUERYBUF, &buf))
{
    // ...
}

buffer = mmap (NULL, buf.length, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, buf.m.offset);
```

## Захват изображения

```
if(-1 == ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_STREAMON, &buf.type)) {
    // ...
}

fd_set fds;
FD_ZERO(&fds);
FD_SET(fd, &fds);
struct timeval tv = {0};
tv.tv_sec = 2;
int r = select(fd+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
if(-1 == r) {
    // ...
}

if(-1 == ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &buf)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -s <size> -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 \
      -preset <preset> -f flv "rtmp://rtmp-publish-url.tld/something/else live=1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ isnullxbh базируется на использовании драйвера *v4l2*. Можно существенно сократить объём усилий, затрачиваемых на написание кода, если воспользоваться библиотекой *openCV*. Простейший пример из доки:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int, char**)
{
    Mat frame;
    //--- INITIALIZE VIDEOCAPTURE
    VideoCapture cap;
    // open the default camera using default API
    cap.open(0);
    /* OR advance usage: select any API backend
    int deviceID = 0;             // 0 = open default camera
    int apiID = cv::CAP_ANY;      // 0 = autodetect default API
    // open selected camera using selected API
    cap.open(deviceID + apiID);
    */
    // check if we succeeded
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        cerr << "ERROR! Unable to open camera\n";
        return -1;
    }
    //--- GRAB AND WRITE LOOP
    cout << "Start grabbing" << endl
        << "Press any key to terminate" << endl;
    for (;;)
    {
        // wait for a new frame from camera and store it into 'frame'
        cap.read(frame);
        // check if we succeeded
        if (frame.empty()) {
            cerr << "ERROR! blank frame grabbed\n";
            break;
        }
        // show live and wait for a key with timeout long enough to show images
        imshow("Live", frame);
        if (waitKey(5) >= 0)
            break;
    }
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```